# Is this an incorrect application of Tutte's theorem of perfect matching for bipartite graphs?

Tags: determinant, inverse, bipartite-graphs, matching-theory

[image]

This is an extract from a conference paper. It seems the authors are invoking Tutte's theorem (since [12] refers to the 1947 paper) to conclude that a matrix $J(x)$ with given numerical entries is invertible. I have seen it explicitly mentioned that the non-singular determinant condition in Tutte's theorem is not tested numerically but as a polynomial identity.
Surely there is a problem here ?  If I follow this reasoning here then the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1\\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ should be invertible ?

Update: The authors state in the paper "However, the invertibility of J(x) depends on x, and is thus hard to characterize. For this reason, we resort to studying the generic rank of J(x), which is the maximal rank over all possible values for the non-zero entries of J(x)."

Comment: The tiny extract is not helpful, but maybe the word "in general" is load-bearing: if a graph has a perfect matching, then almost all matrices associated to it will have full rank. Who knows if this makes sense given the context of the rest of the paper.

Comment: What about the singular matrix that I "prove" is invertible following the logic here ? Doesn't that invalidate their claim ?

Comment: Not if they don't mean that all matrices like that have full rank. The fact that you can screenshot a paragraph of a paper to make it look like it's saying something false doesn't mean that the authors meant to make that false claim.

Comment: Ah, I read before and after the result and what you say makes sense - "However, the invertibility of J(x) depends on x, and is thus hard to characterize. For this reason, we resort to studying the generic rank of J(x), which is the maximal
rank over all possible values for the non-zero entries of J(x)."